# How Authentication manager verifies Credentials?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security in my web application.

Here we have **authentication-manager** & **authentication-provider** where we are providing authenticate user details directly or by an service.

Like:

```
 <authentication-manager>  
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />  
 </authentication-manager>
```

How it is internally performing the verifications. Where is the verification logic present ?

What is going on internally ?

Can anyone suggest with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring security Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/) is your friend !

AuthenticationManager is an interface. The default implementation is `ProviderManager` that gets a list of `AuthenticationProvider`. Each `AuthenticationProvider` is tried in sequence until one can decide for the authentication credentials proposed.

Here, the `<authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />` declares a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. The `DaoAuthenticationProvider` loads user information from the `UserDetailsService` (here `loginService`) and compares the username/password combination with the values supplied at login. If all is fine, it populates an `AuthenticationToken` with the values retrieved from `loginService` and passes id back to the `AuthenticationManager`. If credentials are wrong, it throws an `AuthenticationException`

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this :

Security-application-context.xml :

```
   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

In the above code, you can see authentication manager indicates user-service-ref is LoginServiceImpl and use BCrypt encode with 11 rounds for encryption. Then It looks for Classes with LoginServiceImpl, mentioned below :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");}
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }

    public LoginServiceImpl() {
    }
}
```

As you see it calls a database method by searching in the database for the user. If found, then a new person is build based upon UserDetails class, as below, I am doing it in assembler :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        boolean enabled = userEntity.isEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        }
}
```

These other guys indicate if account is not expired, not locked, and other details. I hope you followed the procedure.